# Как работает функция rand на машинном уровне

Tags: случайные-числа

Во множестве языков есть генератор случайных чисел и я довольно часто использую его у себя на сайте. Но вот меня начал интересовать вопрос, а как работает этот генератор? Не может же он просто ниоткуда выбрать число, значит должна быть привязка к чему-то для выбора. Как эти функции выбирают число? Может кто-то из вас знает ответ на этот вопрос, мне бы было очень интересно узнать.

Comment: Я как-то недавно спросил у преподавателя по программированию, говорит самые чистые случайные числа берут из "белого шума" в Радио Локационной Станции у военных. Но этот способ дорогой, и применяется только военными.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Генератор случайных чисел на то и генератор что он не получает откуда-то настоящие случайные числа каждый раз. Напротив, или вы его инициализируете каким-то в самом деле случайным числом, или он сам делает это автоматически при первом использовании.

Это само по себе здорово потому что можно писать предсказуемые программы, тогда, когда *вам* это нужно, так как последовательность чисел выдаваемая таким генератором явно определяется исходным числом (seed).

С другой стороны если вы на вход такому генератору дадите недостаточно случайное число (например, текущее время в секундах), которое злоумышленник сможет угадать, то вас ждут неприятности.

Откуда правильно брать "настоящие" случайные числа (настоящие в той мере что никто не может их угадать) - проблема широкая. Лучше не выдумывать, а брать эти числа у ОС через стандартные механизмы получения энтропии. В Linux это `/dev/urandom` и системный вызов [getrandom](https://lwn.net/Articles/606141/). В других ОС есть свои специфичные методы получения случайных чисел.

Отдельной проблемой является всевозможный софт, который не использует системные источники энтропии по причинам лени разработчика ли по причинам ошибок. С такой проблемой сталкивались и [ssh в Debian](https://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571), и в PHP с uniqid (хоть даже это отмечено в документации), и [прокалывалась фирма Sony](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-12116051), [и так далее, и тому подобное](https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/).

Как вы можете догадаться, системные источники энтропии тоже откуда-то пополняются. В Linux первичными источниками энтропии служат всевозможные случайные события вроде движения мышки пользователем или задержек при обращении к дискам. Кроме того, нет проблемы использовать "железные" источники энтропии, которые или [продаются как отдельные устройства](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB), или встроены в [TPM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module), присутствующий во многих современных ноутбуках.

Comment: "он не получает откуда-то настоящие случайные числа" - тогда это генератор ПСЕВДО случайных чисел.

Comment: Мы живём с вами в реальном мире. Если в реальном мире *никто* не может угадать какое следующее число выдаст ваш PRNG, то какая разница есть ли у них приставка "псевдо" или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Все сильно зависит от реализации: языка, платформы, опций сборки. Скорее всего, ничем "случайным" это и не пахнет: используется, линейный конгруэнтый генератор, либо же Mersenne Twister. Чисто программная реализация, короче.

Comment: ну, не совсем. Реализация программная но инициализация идет чистым рандомом

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, распиши поподробнее, пожалуйста =)

Comment: @AndrioSkur "но инициализация идет чистым рандомом" - какие ваши доказательства на примере MSVCRT или PHP, например? Более того, нельзя детерминированными алгоритмами получить N+1 бит энтропии из N бит

Comment: @LexHobbit не распишу, потому что расписывать 10-20 генераторов не вижу ни малейшего смысла, если вы сами не желаете этим озаботиться.

Comment: Почему нельзя? Возьмите длинную строку из чего угодно, хоть нулей и зашифруйте их AES случайным ключем. Получите кучу байт, по всем понятиям являющихся случайными. Примерно так работают современные PRNG. [Читайте тут про urandom](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) и [про AES тоже](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62877/would-it-be-secure-to-generate-random-number-using-aes).

Comment: @sanmai потому что закон сохранения информации. Возьмем всем известную строку нулей и будем ее шифровать AES. Но в силу "особенностей" генератора, ключей шифрования может быть всего N. Сколько нужно будет попыток, чтобы угадать случайную последовательность в таком случае? Тоже N, о чем я и говорил. И так будет для любого(!) детерминированного(!) алгоритма. Хоть это Mersenne Twister с 32 битами энтропии, хоть AES с 256.

Comment: Закон сохранения информации - это очень здорово и хорошо, но он применим для замкнутых систем без новых источников информации. У нас же источник есть - случайный ключ. Мы его получили *извне*. Нужно будет, ещё один получим.

Comment: @sanmai да хоть откуда. Если такой ключ всегда один - последовательность тоже всегда одна. Займитесь на досуге угадыванием начального seed'а хоть того же Mersenne Twister, недели через две может поймете, что не смотря на адовый период, количество возможных последовательностей не превышает числа seed'ов.

Comment: Не превышает, но что вы таки предлагаете? Давайте рассмотрим варианты атаки на такой PRNG. Что нужно чтобы угадать какой из  входных ключей на, пусть, 128 бит использовался имея известное случайное число из последовательности или несколько? Сколько на это потребуется времени? Что если ключ поменялся пока вы собирали значения?..

Comment: @sanmai если все-таки не превышает - предлагаю в следующий раз не спрашивать, почему нельзя увеличить энтропию детерминированными алгоритмами.

Comment: Не буду, убедили.